# How to unset $page['#attached']['html_head_link'] from head?

Tags: 8, meta-tags

Help me with this question please: how to unset `html_head_link` from pages in my Drupal 8.0.3 site.

I mean, delete this META:

```
<link rel="delete-form" href="/node/{id}/delete" />
<link rel="edit-form" href="/node/{id}/edit" />
<link rel="version-history" href="/node/{id}/revisions" />
<link rel="revision" href="/mypage" />
```

I try this in MYTHEME.theme file:

```
function MYTHEME_page_attachments_alter(array &$page) {    
  foreach ($page['#attached']['html_head_link'] as $key => $value) {
    unset($page['#attached']['html_head_link'][$key]);
  }
}
```

But this do nothing...

Comment: https://www.drupal.org/node/2406533

Comment: This is no solution..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK. I found fresh module for this trouble. Module's author use `hook_entity_view_alter()` for implements head render. Check out their [git respository](https://github.com/enjoyiacm/unset_html_head_link) to download the module and get the full code with comments.

Answer (score 0):

```
function program_html_head_alter(&$head_elements) {
  unset($head_elements['system_meta_generator']);
  foreach ($head_elements as $key => $element) {
    if (isset($element['#attributes']['rel']) && $element['#attributes']['rel'] == 'canonical') {
      unset($head_elements[$key]); 
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: This code do nothing too.